# How to use RewriteRule with URLs like bit.ly?

Tags: apache

I don't know if they really using a RewriteRule (Apache mod_rewrite) for this, but if we append an URL after the URL of bit.ly (ie: `http://bit.ly/http://www.somesite.com/`), it takes the URL appended as a parameter (`http://bit.ly/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.somesite.com%2F`).

Someone knows how to do that, maybe with a RewriteRule or something else?  If so, what can be the regex to manage this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine their rewrite rule looks something like this:

```
 RewriteRule ^(http.*)$ ?u=$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [R]
```

Couldn't help but fiddle around with this:  Accepts multiple protocols and avoids appending the ? if there is no query string:

```
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^$)
   RewriteRule ^((http|ftp).*)$ ?u=$1 [B,R,L]

   RewriteRule ^((http|ftp).*)$ ?u=$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [B,R,L]
```

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html says: "To combine a new query string with an old one, use the [QSA] flag." Note that the actual bit.ly site escapes the question mark as part of the URL though.

Comment: QSA combines the new query with old, but bit.ly passes it as part of the parameter.

Comment: I have a demo of my updated rule working properly at http://www.cerebraldonkey.com/mod_rewrite/http://www.stackexchange.com/?param=foo

Comment: The question mark before the passed query string should really be "%3F" (urlencoded) to properly indicate it's part of the "u" parameter, and not another query string tacked on. And all ampersands in the passed query string should be urlencoded too, but not sure how to do that...

Comment: If you want it to encode the rewritten query string, adding the `B` option will do the trick (i.e.: `[B,R,L]`)  I had noticed bit.ly wasn't doing that at the time.

Comment: I guess either way it's definitely doing that now.  Updated to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably something in these lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And then have `index.php` do a:

1. search database to see if link is ok or flagged (badware, spam, etc)
2. mark visit in stats database
3. throw http 301 headers on the user for a proper redirect